# How do you assign ressourses when using PyTorch on AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I wish to use AWS Sagemaker in to train a PyTorch model. I am wondering how do I assign resources to the task? if I had my own computer I would use:

```
device = torch.cuda("cuda0")
```

Is it the same for AWS Sagemaker

Answer (score 0):

Yes the device code is same with your own computer. However better thing to do is

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

If you want to look more details about PyTorch on Sagemaker, there is an official documentation https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html